# App is crashing when a banner add is added to it

Tags: java, android, admob

#### I created a test app for ad and it worked there but in my main project app same code is crashing the app

Same Code In New Project Works fine but in my existing project it causes crash please help me.
Thanks

**Manifest File**

```
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/testAppID"/>

        </activity>
```

**My MainActivity Code**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //testAppID = sample ID provided by admob
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "@strings/testAppID");

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
 }
```

**Erros :**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    
    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:  to add a valid  *
    * App ID inside the AndroidManifest. Google Ad Manager publishers should     *
    * follow instructions here:                            *
    ******************************************************************************
    
    
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6727)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:268)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1995)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7539)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    
    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:  to add a valid  *
    * App ID inside the AndroidManifest. Google Ad Manager publishers should     *
    * follow instructions here:                            *
    ******************************************************************************
    
    
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabg.attachInfo(Unknown Source:16)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:3)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7187)
            ... 10 more
```

Comment: Check that you play service library version in working project and main project is same or not

Comment: the problem is with manifest meta data please check your android:value tag it should be correct
eg:-android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata tag must be inside the application tag. try to move it out of the activity tag. See the [doc](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) for more information

```
<application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/testAppID"/>
</application>
```